How would ZFC not having a standard model of $\omega$ actually prove that ZFC proves false arithmetical statements?
From a paper by Nik Weaver (I quote the whole passage of interest):

I just made the point that we have no a priori reason to believe that ZFC has a canonical model. One consequence of this is that we should be skeptical of the actual truth of number-theoretic results proven in ZFC that are not provable in predicative systems. These could only be trusted if we had some reason to believe that ZFC has models in which ω is standard. Now we may believe that ZFC is probably consistent because (1) no inconsistency has been found yet and (2) we have built up some sort of intuition for ZFC which tells us that it is consistent. I personally find these arguments persuasive but not compelling. They suggest that ZFC probably does have a model. However, they tell us nothing about whether it has a model with a standard ω. This seems to me more likely to be false than true. Given the recursive compexity of ZFC (as measured by its proof-theoretic ordinal, and already suggested by the circularity of the power set of ω mentioned in Section 1) we should not expect that there is such a model absent some special reason to do so. The presumption should be that ZFC has no such model and hence that there are probably some false statements of first order arithmetic that are provable in ZFC.

My observations:

ZFC supposedly proves false arithmetical statements.

The purported basis for this claim is that ZFC might not have a model with a standard $\omega$.



From what I understand, the $\omega$ in a model $M$ of ZFC is 'standard' if and only if externally we can show it's isomorphic to the usual $(\mathbb{N},+,\times,0,\text{succ},<)$ structure. Why you would take this structure as the model of absolute truth about the natural numbers wouldn't make any sense though if you doubt that such a structure is standard. But even if you accept this argument, I'm confused about whether the $(\mathbb{N},+,\times,0,\text{succ},<)$ structure is actually standard or not. On the one hand, it kind of behaves like the standard 'theory' of arithmetic by definition (otherwise it would make no sense to use it as a basis to judge the soundness of other theories, unless there is some other characterization of the standard model of arithmetic of which I am unaware). On the other hand, in every model of ZFC it may turn out to be non-standard. My inclination would be, even if every model of ZFC had a non-standard $\omega$, to ignore this result, since these are only theorems of the meta-theory and not direct theorems themselves (similar to how we can ignore ZFC being consistent with its own inconsistency).

This is why it feels like there's some kind of a gap between saying that no model of ZFC has an $\omega$ that is standard and suddenly claiming ZFC can prove false arithmetical statements. It seems like at most you can claim that the structure $(\mathbb{N},+,\times,0,\text{succ},<)$ we use for arithmetic is in some sense not right because it has this property, but then again I don't trust my intuition that this is a property the 'right' model of arithmetic should have.
How does one actually justify that ZFC proves false arithmetical statements on the basis that ZFC has no models with standard $\omega$? Am I right in wondering whether this is even a rigorously formulated sentence? What does Nik Weaver mean by this passage?
source: Paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1680 "Is set theory indispensable?" Submitted on 11 May, 2009
Which I found from his response to this question
Edit: This is clearly different from the marked duplicate, and it is quite shocking these should be marked as the same. The supposed duplicate question is merely asking whether there are models of ZFC with non-standard $\omega$, whereas I am asking why someone said if all models are then something else is true (namely ZFC proves false arithmetic statements). I already know such models exist, and am asking a wholly different question.

I think they mean that if no $\omega$ model of $ZFC$ would indicate, or give evidence, that $ZFC$ actually proves a false arithmetic statement. It is possible to cook up a system which proves only true arithmetic statements but does not have standard $\omega$. For example, take $T$ to be True first order arithmetic, add a constant $c$ to the language  plus infinitely many axioms which state $c$ is not equal to a standard number. Such system will only imply true arithmetic statements but will never have a standard $\omega$.

Please add to your question the complete reference of Nik Weaver's paper.

@Gonçalo Is this sufficient?

Yes. Thank you.

The claimed duplicate question asks if Con(ZFC) implies there is an $\omega$-model of ZFC. You are asking if "ZFC is arithmetically sound" implies there is an $\omega$-model of ZFC. Though a negative answer to the first question does not immediately imply one for the second, the reasoning in the answer generalizes, as remarked in the answer. Someone expressed similar confusion that the answer is "just showing non-$\omega$ models exist" in the comments and I suggest you read the responses.

@spaceisdarkgreen oh, i see. I had no idea it was like that. It's like what Giorgio Genovesi pointed out then right? I mistakenly thought the only content of the question was asking if Con(ZFC) implied there is an $\omega$-model of ZFC, and it made sense how the existence of non-$\omega$ models would disprove that implication (unless I'm underthinking it). When you say the reasoning generalizes, is that to say "ZFC is arithmetically sound" is the stronger '$\beta$' Noah Schweber talks about in his comments?

I don't know what the future of this question is. I am ok with deleting it. On the one hand that'd be fine, on the other it would make it easier for future people to find the answer given it was in the comments of the other post (which wasn't suggested to me when I drafted the question) and also (at least to me) the connection wasn't obvious or direct

@PineappleFish Yeah, Giorgio is saying that the arithmetic soundness does not imply an $\omega$-model as well. Having a $\beta$ model is stronger than having an $\omega$-model. Arithmetic soundness is weaker. The argument is that the existence of an $\omega$ model of ZFC implies Con(ZFC + ZFC is arithmetically sound), so such an implication would violate the incompleteness theorem. The reason is that an $\omega$ model of ZFC is a model of "ZFC + ZFC is arithmetically sound", since it agrees with the universe about the first order properties of $\omega$ and what statements ZFC proves.

@PineappleFish Yes, I'd recommend you leave it up. Despite my comment attempting to explain that the closure wasn't unfounded, I am on the fence about voting to re-open myself, as there are other aspects to your question and I agree even though I think that the duplicate answers the main mathematical content, this isn't obvious.

What Weaver seems to imply here in the last sentence -- that arithmetical soundness of $\sf ZFC$ implies it has an $\omega$-model -- can be made precise without trivializing it, but it is not correct. For instance, we can ask if $\sf ZFC$, which doesn't prove the consequent, proves the implication, and the answer is no (assuming it is consistent, of course). The correct model-theoretic equivalence would be that $\sf ZFC$ is arithmetically sound if and only if it has a model whose natural numbers are elementarily equivalent to the natural numbers, as opposed to isomorphic.
The reason that the implication can't be proved is basically given the answer to this question, which the present question was previously closed as a duplicate of. Generally, if we have some "strong correctness" and "weak correctness" proposition, a strategy to separate them is to show that strong correctness implies the consistency of weak correctness. Thus if weak correctness implied strong correctness, it would imply the consistency of weak correctness, in violation of the incompleteness theorem.
Here, "weak correctness" is arithmetic soundness of $\sf ZFC$ and "strong correctness" is $\sf ZFC$ having an $\omega$ model. And indeed, $\sf ZFC$ having an $\omega$-model implies the consistency of $\sf ZFC $ + $\sf ZFC$ is arithmetically sound, since this theory is true in any $\omega$-model of $\sf ZFC$. To see this, just observe that the model's $\omega$ being standard implies that a) the first-order properties of the natural numbers, according to the model, are the same as external and b) the consequences of $\sf ZFC$, according to the model, are the same as external.
This detail probably doesn't make much of a difference to Weaver's argument. He probably just thinks the only reasonable justification for $\sf ZFC$'s soundness would involve arguing the stronger statement that it has an $\omega$-model, or perhaps that's simply the usual argument he's been confronted with.
Regarding your observations, I don't know that I fully understand what you're saying, but think a lot of your confusion is coming from the misconception that Weaver's metatheory, or the appropriate metatheory here, anyway, is $\sf ZFC$. But why would we use this if we were skeptical of $\sf ZFC$'s soundness? Our external natural numbers are "standard" (either in some platonic sense or by fiat), even if Weaver is right that no model of $\sf ZFC$ has an $\omega$ isomorphic to them. Of course $\sf ZFC$ would not be a correct theory to describe our set theoretical background then. It would presumably be some weaker set theory that is arithmetically sound and has an $\omega$ model. I don't understand the connection with being able to ignore that $\lnot\sf Con(ZFC)$ is consistent with $\sf ZFC.$ If a bad thing is consistent, sure, that is ok, it maybe just means it'll take stronger axioms prove things are good, not that things are necessarily bad. But here we are talking about a thing actually happening, not just that it is consistent that it happens.
